# SQLite insert No such column error on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, error-handling

I have problem when inserting data from CSV. The CSV part works but the insert returns following error. Basically it says that there does not exist the column. Below this is the code and also the code of the database.

```
09-06 17:52:22.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-06 17:52:22.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19168): android.database.sqlite.
SQLiteException: no such column: Ananas (code 1): , while compiling: 
INSERT INTO food (name, sacharides, glycemia, category1) VALUES    
(Ananas, 13, 45,1)

09-06 17:52:22.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19168):    
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement
(Native Method)
```

Here is the code which fails.

```
            FoodDatabase myHelper = new FoodDatabase(getApplicationContext());
            myDatabase = myHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            String[] nextLine;
            try {
                while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
                    System.out.println(nextLine[0]+ " " + nextLine[1]
                            +" "+ nextLine[2]);

                    String sql =   "INSERT INTO food (name, sacharides, glycemia, category1) " +
                            "VALUES (" + nextLine[0] + ", " + nextLine[1] + ", "  + nextLine[2]+ "," + nextLine[3] +")";
                //  myDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
                    myDatabase.execSQL(sql);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here goes how the database looks.

```
public class FoodDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String TABLE_FOOD = "food";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
  public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
  public static final String COLUMN_SACHARIDES = "sacharides";
  public static final String COLUMN_SACHARIDESPORTION = "sacharides_per_portion";
  public static final String COLUMN_PORTIONSIZE = "portion_size";
  public static final String COLUMN_GLYCEMIA = "glycemia";
  public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY1 = "category1";
  public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY2 = "category2";
  public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY3 = "category3";




  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tables.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_FOOD + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_NAME
      + " text," + COLUMN_SACHARIDES
      + " real," + COLUMN_PORTIONSIZE
      + " integer," + COLUMN_SACHARIDESPORTION
      + " real," + COLUMN_GLYCEMIA
      + " integer,"+ COLUMN_CATEGORY1
      + " integer," +COLUMN_CATEGORY2
      + " integer," +COLUMN_CATEGORY3
      + " integer);";

  public FoodDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(FoodDatabase.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FOOD);
    onCreate(db);
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure but you might need to have single quotes `''` around the strings inside `VALUES`.
Try:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO food (name, sacharides, glycemia, category1) " +
                            "VALUES ('" + nextLine[0] + "', '" + nextLine[1] + "', '"  + nextLine[2]+ "', '" + nextLine[3] +"' )";
```

Comment: actually the problem seems to be deeper it works when I put away glycemia but when I am adding 4 things at once it will fail no matter how I change the positions etc

Comment: Can you please be a bit specific? Fail means? What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: it returns that it does not know the column glycemia, or if I change it so that I insert also into category2 so it looks insert into food(name,sacharides,category1,category2) values (ananas, 10,12,14) it says it doesn't know column category2

Comment: Firstly, when you are creating the table `COLUMN_CATEGORY1
      + " integer" +COLUMN_CATEGORY2
      + " integer" +COLUMN_CATEGORY3` , don't you need to put `,` after `integer`? Other that that have you updated the table format anytime soon? Delete it and create again, if that's okay.

Comment: I have edited it, already found this :) but it does not help. Oh yeah good point with deleting the database format. How can I do that?

Comment: Either you can do is programatically or manually. Try to google it. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case,

unfortunately table name is mismatched. :^)
take a rest. and going on!